# intercept ReactJS synthetic keydown handler

Tags: reactjs

I understand that React implements its own event delegation system for keydown, keyup and keypress events.

What I would like to do is inject my own app-wide keydown handler at startup that intercepts the synthetic keydown events before they reach any component.  For example, my injected keydown handler might detect and consume certain key combinations that I can use to emit custom debug events.  I specifically want to avoid having to detect such events within a component key handler.

Is this possible, and if so, can anyone point me to a guide?

Answer (score 0):

perhaps this isn't as complex as you think? or unless I understand it the wrong way, you can just use a document.addEventListener in your app.js (which is the top level of your components).

Here's a snippet:

```
var Comp1 = React.createClass({
  _handleKeyDown: function(e) {
    console.clear();
    console.log(e.target.value);
  },
  render: function() {
    return (
      <div>
        your name:
        <input type="text" onKeyDown={this._handleKeyDown} />
      </div>
    );
  }
});

var Comp2 = React.createClass({
  render: function() {
    return (
      <div>
        this is component 2
      </div>
    );
  }
});

var Main = React.createClass({
  componentDidMount: function() {
    document.addEventListener("keydown", this._handleKeyDown);
  },
  _handleKeyDown: function(e) {    
    console.log('keydown from main');
  },
  render: function() {
    return (
      <div>
        <Comp1 />
        <Comp2 />
      </div>
    );
  }
});

React.render(<Main />, document.getElementById('app'));
```

here's the jsbin link:
http://jsbin.com/saxocujovu/edit?js,console,output

is this what you're looking for?

Comment: I still want to take advantage of React's key event delegation.  Won't your method just add a seperate keydown listener?

Comment: so where/what do you want to attach your keydown handler to?

Comment: React already adds it's own keydown handler that handles event delegation.  I want to inject my own keydown handler via EventPluginHub that interfaces with the React one.